# get existing tables from websql database

Tags: javascript, sql, web-sql

I was wondering if it is possible to get the existing tables from a websql database. Is there some sort of query to find these?

I have already found several sqlite examples but these don't work in websql.

Answer (score 8):

Link seems to be dead from Kyaw Tun's answer - this worked for me, just wanted to share unless anyone else is looking for this.

`SELECT tbl_name, sql from sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'`

It will show the original sql used to generate the table - not perfect but should be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can query existing table schema from [sqlite_master](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) table.

For implementation, you can see detail on my open source library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/src/master/js/ydn/db/conn/websql.js

Basically you can get your schema by

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('db name');
db.getSchema(function (schema) {
  console.log(schema);
});
```